# Invalid table when creating new database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have EntityA, EntityA_Child, EntityB and EntityC, they look like this

```
public class EntityA {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Collection<EntityB> EntityBCollection { get; set; }
}

public class EntityA_Child {
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public EntityA EntityA { get; set; }

    public EntityC EntityC { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Collection<EntityC> EntityCCollection { get; set; }
}

public class EntityC { 
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

Previously i had EntityA_Child as a normal complex object, but because i needed to reference another entity, i had to make it a separate entity as complex objects cannot contain references to other entities.

Anyway, this all works in my system, i am writing my unit tests, and when it tries to create the database it fails, saying

> threw exception. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Foreign key 'FK_dbo.EntityA_Child_dbo.EntityC_Id' references invalid table 'dbo.EntityC'.

Now i know this is because EntityA table is being created with a constraint to EntityC, but because EntityC hasnt been created, i get an error.

How can i fix it?

I have to be able to assign a record in EntityC to EntityA.

Is there a way i can tell Entity Framework to create constraints after tables or something?

Answer (score 0):

The EF already adds the foreign key constraint after table creation.

BTW, changing long Id to int Id (had to do so because of my test provider) for me worked. So your problem is different (already created DB?).
This are the SQL Creation statements tha EF runs against the DBMS

```
CREATE TABLE [EntityA_Child] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [EntityA_Id] int null
, [EntityC_Id] int null
);
ALTER TABLE [EntityA_Child] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_EntityA_Child_57aa7524] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [EntityAs] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
);
ALTER TABLE [EntityAs] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_EntityAs_57aa7524] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [EntityBs] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [EntityA_Id] int null
);
ALTER TABLE [EntityBs] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_EntityBs_57aa7524] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [EntityCs] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [EntityB_Id] int null
);
ALTER TABLE [EntityCs] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_EntityCs_57aa7524] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_EntityA_Id] ON [EntityA_Child] ([EntityA_Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_EntityC_Id] ON [EntityA_Child] ([EntityC_Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_EntityA_Id] ON [EntityBs] ([EntityA_Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_EntityB_Id] ON [EntityCs] ([EntityB_Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [EntityA_Child] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EntityA_Child_EntityAs_EntityA_Id
] FOREIGN KEY ([EntityA_Id]) REFERENCES [EntityAs] ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [EntityA_Child] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EntityA_Child_EntityCs_EntityC_Id
] FOREIGN KEY ([EntityC_Id]) REFERENCES [EntityCs] ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [EntityBs] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EntityBs_EntityAs_EntityA_Id] FOREIGN
KEY ([EntityA_Id]) REFERENCES [EntityAs] ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [EntityCs] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EntityCs_EntityBs_EntityB_Id] FOREIGN
KEY ([EntityB_Id]) REFERENCES [EntityBs] ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
```

Comment: Entity framework doesnt create my scripts in that order.  Mine is creating EntityA_Child first and all the constraints.  None of the other tables get created because it errors first

Comment: Very strange... Try to activate the SQL Server profiler to see what EF exactly does.

Comment: Bloody migrations!! Deleted my migrations and now it creates the database fine.  Maybe AutomaticMigrations would of helped me? I will turn this on to see i think

Comment: Probably yes but usually is better to avoid AutomaticMigrations in production environment.